# how to group result with json key name in laravel

Tags: json, laravel

```
user table 
 id name age 
 1  TuTu   3
 2  SuSu   4
 3  YuYu   4
 4  MoMo   4
```

I want to output json like this.

```
[
  {
    "age": 3,
    "user": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "TuTu"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "age": 4,
    "user": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "SuSu"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "YuYu"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "MoMo"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

`User::get()->groupBy("age")` not working expected.

How could add json key age and user like above format in laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer gives you the desired output, however consider using an [API Resource](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources) for JSON Response.

```
$response = [];

User::get()->groupBy('age')->each(function ($item, $key) use (&$response) {
    $temp = [];

    $temp['age'] = $key;

    $temp['user'] = $item->transform(function ($i, $k) {
        unset($i['age']);
        return $i;
    })->all();

    $response[] = $temp;
});

var_dump($response); // Your Output JSON
```